# I am attempting to use .latest() to retrieve the most recent object but I am getting field error and an extra "-"

Tags: python, django, sublimetext2

The code seems pretty innocuous:

```
home_post = Post.objects.latest('-timestamp')
```

but it returns the following error:

```
FieldError at /
Invalid order_by arguments: ['--timestamp']
```

There seems to be an extra "-" that isn't in my code. Where is this coming from? Is sublime adding this? Is this what is actually causing the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`latest` should be passed the field name and only the field name.

If you want to get the "latest" in reverse order you should use [`earliest`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#earliest)

```
Post.objects.earliest('timestamp')
```